# Will running parallel TRUNCATE causing foreign key constraint fails on INSERT (MySQL 8.x)?

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys

Is there something I'm missing or does this seems like a bug with MySQL 8, tried the latest version 8.0.29 and other versions in between. This used to work in 5.7 without issues. Luckily, I was able to reproduce this in bash but we encountered it within our testing setup. It seems like you can get a state where a table has record with the correct id for the foreign key constraint but MySQL still throws an error.

Basic setup:

- Create table A
- Create table B, this has a foreign key constraint on id of table A
- parallel TRUNCATE table A and table B (disable the session FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS)
- insert into table A
- insert into table B <-- this will fail, not always but if you run it 100 times it will fail with foreign key constraint error.

Here is the code to reproduce it. This will put MySQL into a bad state, you can even connect to the database and try inserting and it will fail.

```
#!/bin/bash
DB_USER='root';
DB_PASSWD='root';

DB_NAME='mysql_8_bug';
TABLE_A='a';
TABLE_B='b';

set -m

#setup
mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD << EOF
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $DB_NAME DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
EOF

mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME << EOF
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_A, $TABLE_B;
EOF


mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME << EOF
CREATE TABLE $TABLE_A (id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
EOF

mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME << EOF
CREATE TABLE $TABLE_B
(id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
int_a_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_a_id FOREIGN KEY (int_a_id) REFERENCES a (id));
EOF
#end of setup


for i in {0..100}
do

#run truncate in parallel
  mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME --execute="SET @@session.FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; TRUNCATE TABLE $TABLE_A; SET @@session.FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;" &
  mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME --execute="SET @@session.FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; TRUNCATE TABLE $TABLE_B; SET @@session.FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;" &
  wait

  mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME --execute="INSERT INTO $TABLE_A (id) VALUES (1);"


  mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME --execute="INSERT INTO $TABLE_B (int_a_id) VALUES (1);"
  if [ $? -gt 0 ]
  then
  echo "It Happened!!! You can now check the database you will see that table a has value of id 1. The database will be in a bad state, running INSERT in table b will not work."
  exit 0
  fi

done
```

Comment: I saw you (or someone with your name :) also reported this as a bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107532 so wait for the MySQL team to respond. I tested your script and I also can observe the issue. It doesn't happen every time, but if I re-run the script it may happen.

Comment: Thanks Bill. After looking at the code and double checking everything, I was 99% sure this is a MySQL bug and submitted as such to the team. I'm glad someone else was able to reproduce it.